# Component identification Pi Zero w V1.1

Tags: pi-zero-w

I have a Pi Zero W V1.1 with some missing components. please see the attached picture.

**Missing components are are circled red and green.**
[image: Pi Zero with solder pads circled]

if any one is able to help me identify these I would be extremely grateful.

I look forward to any reply

Comment: how do you know that they are missing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have 2 Pi Zero modules and when comparing them I can see that some components are missing. In fact, a friend gave me his Pi, he said the Wi-Fi stopped working. On closer inspection I realized the missing components are located near the Wi-Fi part of the board. He things he might have accidently knocked them. I’m guessing he wasn't very careful in looking after it. Being a bit heavy handed I think. I feel it’s a shame to bin it as it’s such an easy fix. I'm a strong believer in trying to repair electronic items before sending them to land fill.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most the RPF engineers will say:
https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rpizero/raspberry-pi-zero-w-reduced-schematics.pdf

Maybe their labeling or appearance on the working pi gives some clues?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).